# Can MEng Students Get R&D Jobs in Robotics Area in the US?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, job-search

I got the Mechanical MEng offer of a top university a few weeks ago. I'm still not sure if I want to peruse a PhD but I do want a job about R&D related to robotics in the future. I'm sure there must be some people in the same situation like me. So here is the problem, can MEng students get R&D jobs in robotics area in the US? Or it is necessary to get a PhD or MS in order to get in such jobs.

I have several specific questions:

- How likely can MEng students get into PhD programs of top
  universities after the MEng program? Comparing with MS students?
- For the R&D jobs in robotics area, is PhD required? Or MS students also have a great chance?

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Why do you distinguish between MEng and MS? PhDs aren't normally required for industry jobs. R&D is a bit different from academic research.

Comment: @Buffy: An MEng degree typically has a lower bar to achieve than an MS. The MEng is generally implemented as a fifth year tacked into a bachelor’s degree to “supercharge” it, whereas an MS in engineering is a separate two-year degree.

Comment: Is it a UK specific thing? I don't recognize it as "typical" in US, anyway. Though some universities have their own degree setup.

Comment: Widespread in the US, I don’t know if it shows up in the UK.